# Support for other git repositories except GitHub

Tags: git, repository, qooxdoo

Is it possible to publish a package in another git repository and use it via `qx package install` command like with official *qooxdoo* repository? For example I want use [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) for storing my qooxdoo projects.

Comment: No, unfortunately the Qooxdoo compiler accepts only the `Username/Repository` convention as a package reference and will only search on GitHub to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the current system is hardcoded to use GitHub as a registry and package source. It would be great to have a system that is more generalized and works with plugins that would allow to connect other providers. However, it is not a priority and probably won't be implemented any time soon. You are welcome to look at the code and assess how much work it would be to make it more general. It would probably require id suffixes like "bitbucket:" (github being the default fall-back id) that would tell the the install script where to look for downloads.

https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo-compiler/blob/master/source/class/qx/tool/cli/commands/package/